# Disable two-finger horizontal scroll

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch

Is there any way I could disable two finger swipes for horizontal scrolling on the Mac. I want to configure it for moving between tabs (using a 3rd party app called BetterTouchTool)

Edit:
Oh I should mention that I've already disabled the option 'swipe between pages using left/right two finger scrolls', but that just disables the back/forward feature — not the horizontal scrolling functionality itself. (And even though most pages don't have space horizontal scrolling, the action still produces a "dummy" movement.)

Comment: can't you just uncheck the option in the trackpad settings ? I don't know how you could assign to another app though

Comment: have already tried that — see edit

Comment: did you solved it? I'm having the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you have disabled two finger swipes between pages in trackpad preferences then you should be able to configure it in BetterTouchTool by assigning keyboard shortcuts for those gestures. Swipes are generally fast and scrolls are generally slow. So you should be able to get both working side by side.

You can disable all scrolls if it really bothers you from accessibility section. In recent versions of OS X, disabling only horizontal scrolling is no more an option for built-in trackpad. Check [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3448).

[image]